# Random YouTube video player

Tags: beginner, php, random, video, youtube

I just finished making this quick and dirty random YouTube video player for fun and learning.  Before I get started, by "random" I mean selecting a video from a list of videos using PHP RNG, not truly random and not random as in "any video from YouTube".  It also uses the YouTube API to get information like the video title from just the ID and accepts inputs of the entire YouTube video URL or just the ID.  I want to know if anything I did in this is a bad practice or if there are better ways of doing the things I did because I am not a professional PHP coder and I want to start coding with good habits so later I am not making mistakes.

Here is the github repo: https://github.com/desultory/RandomYoutubeVideo

here is the code for each component:
config.php:

```
<?php
$ytapikey= 'your youtube API key here';
```

edit.php:

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>">
    <h1>Input video ID of a video to add to the list<h1>
    <input type="text" name="videoid" placeholder="Video ID of video to add" autofocus>
    <br><br>
    <h1>Select a video to remove<h1>
    <select name="remove">
        <option>None</option>
        <?php
            //checks to see if the file exists before continuing
            if (file_exists('videos')) {
                //reads and unserializes the videos file
                $videos = unserialize(file_get_contents('videos'));
                //loops through the videos array to get components of each video
                foreach($videos as $element) {
                    $videoid = $element[0];
                    $videotitle = $element[1];
                    //formats the video details for html
                    echo "\t\t<option value=\"$videoid\">$videotitle</option>";
                }
            }
        ?>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" text="Update list"/>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
//includes the config to get youtube api token
include 'config.php';
//checks to see if the video id is set and not empty
if (isset($_POST['videoid']) && $_POST['videoid'] !== "") {
    //gets video id from post
    $videoid = $_POST['videoid'];
    //checks to see if the video id contains the string youtube so it can extract the video id
    if (stripos($videoid, 'youtube') !== FALSE) {
        //parses the string to get query information
        parse_str(parse_url($videoid, PHP_URL_QUERY), $videoquery);
        //sets the video ID to be just the v query which is the video id
        $videoid = $videoquery['v'];
    }
    //gets the title snippet using the youtube api
    $videoinfo = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id='.$videoid.'&key='.$ytapikey.'&fields=items(snippet(title))'));
    //sets videotitle to be just the title portion of the snippet
    $videotitle = $videoinfo->items[0]->snippet->title;
    //checks to see if videos exists so it can read it and then concatenate it
    if (file_exists('videos')) {
        //reads and unserializes the videos file
        $videos = unserialize(file_get_contents('videos'));
        //adds a new element containing the new video id and title
        $videos[count($videos)] = [$videoid, $videotitle];
    } else {
        //makes a new array for videos and adds the video id and title
        $videos[0] = [$videoid, $videotitle];
    }
    //checks to see if the video is valid based on the title found before writing
    if ($videotitle !== NULL) {
        //serializes and writes new video file
        file_put_contents('videos', serialize($videos));
        //refreshes the page
        header("Refresh:0");
    } else {
        echo 'Invalid video';
    }
}
//checks to see if remove is set and isn't none
if (isset($_POST['remove']) && $_POST['remove'] !== "None") {
    //gets the video id to be removed from the post
    $videoid = $_POST['remove'];
    //reads and unserializes the videos file
    $videos = unserialize(file_get_contents('videos'));
    //sets the counter to 0
    $counter = 0;
    //loops through the videos array
    foreach($videos as $element) {
        //checks to see if the element contains the video ID to be removed
        if(strpos($element[0], $videoid) !== FALSE) {
            //Removes the array element that contains that video ID
            array_splice($videos, $counter, 1);
        }
    //increments the counter
    $counter++;
    }
    //serializes and writes new videos file
    file_put_contents('videos', serialize($videos));
}
?>
```

index.php:

```
<?php
//checks to see if video file exists
if (file_exists('videos')) {
    //reads and unserializes the videos file
    $videos = unserialize(file_get_contents('videos'));
    //selects a random video and gets the ID
    $videoid = $videos[array_rand($videos)][0];
} else {
    echo 'No video list found, if you have not configured it, go to edit.php';
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
    <title>Infinite Random Videos</title>
</head>
<style>
html, body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.video{
  overflow: hidden;
  position: abslute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
</style>
<body>
    <div class="video">
        <iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" src="https://youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $videoid;?>?autoplay=1&loop=1&controls=0&disablekb=1&fs=0&iv_load_policy=3&rel=0&showinfo=0&modestbranding=1"></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

videos:

```
a:4:{i:0;a:2:{i:0;s:11:"HdGf0NhJ6Wc";i:1;s:17:"Learning to Yo-yo";}i:1;a:2:{i:0;s:11:"3AIInqUwQE8";i:1;s:16:"Learning to Swim";}i:2;a:2:{i:0;s:11:"gQXUQRFNhUw";i:1;s:12:"Making Toast";}i:3;a:2:{i:0;s:11:"UlFPsVu8b5Y";i:1;s:8:"Pet Rock";}}
```

Note:

I could use SQL as a storage method but I want this to be "portable" and to be able to work on a weberver without SQL access

Answer (score 1):

Asking for a review on code that is admittedly "quick and dirty" might defeat the purpose of a code review. You should clean it up as best you can before requesting a review.

The first and most obvious problem is the interpolation of PHP and HTML. Your PHP should ideally be in another file, or at the very least, isolated above the doctype. Don't do a bunch of PHP processing in the middle of an HTML document. Note, in particular, that a header call won't work after you've started output.

Prefer JSON over serialize. `serialize` is PHP specific. Anything you serialize with PHP become useless without PHP, on the other hand, if you use JSON and need to debug something you can copy your data into any number of online JSON formatters, for example.

If you're going to echo an error message above the doctype, make sure you exit the script afterwords or your just going to send the browser broken HTML which may not render as expected.